# Check for match in one column of data frame to one of multiple other columns in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have a df with 4 columns. How can I add a column that indicates whether the string in col 1 matches a string in any of cols 1-3?

df

```
    species_A   species_1   species_2   species_3
1   Clostridium breve   Clostridium breve   Eggerthella lenta   Bacillus cereus
2   Splactus blandum Splactus plantarum Splactus pentosus Clostridium adolescentis
3   Rotoroides ovatus   Rotoroides ovatus Pseudomonas oryzihabitans Stenotrophomonas maltophilia
4   Bacillus licheniformis  Phytorotor sp.  Cutirotorium acnes  Rotoroides ovatus
5   Clostridium longum  Clostridium longum  Sphingomonas melonis    Phytorotor sp.
6 Odorirotor splanchnicus   Clostridium longum  Odorirotor splanchnicus Stenotrophomonas maltophilia
```

I want to add a column 'match' with T/F on whether species_A matches species_1 OR species_2 OR species_3:

```
    species_A   species_1   species_2   species_3   Matches
1   Clostridium breve   Clostridium breve   Eggerthella lenta   Bacillus cereus TRUE
2   Splactus bandum Splactus plantarum  Splactus pentosus Clostridium adolescentis  TRUE
3   Rotoroides ovatus   Rotoroides ovatus Pseudomonas oryzihabitans Stenotrophomonas maltophilia    TRUE
4   Bacillus licheniformis  Phytorotor sp.  Cutirotorium acnes  Rotoroides ovatus   FALSE
5   Clostridium longum  Clostridium longum  Sphingomonas melonis    Phytorotor sp.  TRUE
6 Odorirotor splanchnicus   Clostridium longum  Odorirotor splanchnicus Stenotrophomonas maltophilia    TRUE
```

Based on other threads I've tried using lapply and sapply, but I can't seem to feed the species_A column as a set of patterns.

```
lapply(df[2:4], function(x) match(x, d$species_A))

sapply(df[2:4],
              function(x) grepl(d$species_A, x, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
rowSums(df$species_A == df[2:4]) > 0
```

Your data is difficult to import because of the spaces (use `dput(df)` to share a copy/pasteable version of a data frame), so I'll demonstrate on some fake data:

```
## copy/pasteable data:
df = data.frame(
  species_A = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  species_1 = c("A", "A", "X", "X"),
  species_2 = c("A", "B", "X", "X"),
  species_3 = c("A", "X", "X", "D")
)

df
#   species_A species_1 species_2 species_3
# 1         A         A         A         A
# 2         B         A         B         X
# 3         C         X         X         X
# 4         D         X         X         D


## make comparisons
df$species_A == df[2:4]
#      species_1 species_2 species_3
# [1,]      TRUE      TRUE      TRUE
# [2,]     FALSE      TRUE     FALSE
# [3,]     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
# [4,]     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE

## see if there are any TRUEs
rowSums(df$species_A == df[2:4]) > 0
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

## put it together
df$result = rowSums(df$species_A == df[2:4]) > 0

df
#   species_A species_1 species_2 species_3 result
# 1         A         A         A         A   TRUE
# 2         B         A         B         X   TRUE
# 3         C         X         X         X  FALSE
# 4         D         X         X         D   TRUE
```

`lapply` and `sapply` aren't great choices here because they loop over columns 2:4 and return separate results for columns 2:4.  We could also use them with `rowSums`, `sapply(df[2:4], "==", df$species_A)` is a longer way to write `df$species_A == df[2:4]`.

Comment: Turns out this isn't working on my installation (R version 3.6.2). I get the following when I run "df$species_A == df[2:4]":  Error in df$species_A == df[2:4] : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.data.frame") for "==" 
2: In df$species_A == df[2:4] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: Ah, seems like at least some of your columns are factors. Convert them to `character` vectors. Something like `df[] = lapply(df, as.character)`. (R 4.0 switched the default for data frames from `factor` to `character` - a change that's been a long time coming.)